# getting second difference with sql statement

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgresql which stores time stamp with timezone for every row inserted.

How can I use postgresql's function to find a the difference in seconds from the timestamp in one of the rows already inserted to the current postgresql server time stamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the column name is `ts` and the table name is `t`, you can query like this:

```
select current_timestamp - max(ts) from t;
```

If the table contains large amount of data, this query will be very slow. In that case, you should have index on the timestamp column.